# How to fix the late key press problem in access

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, textbox

I have a textbox that's purpose is to update the subtotal value whenever there is a key stroke in access. 
Now the problem with this is that the OnKey press event function updates the subtotal value after 1 extra key press. The text box is named as QuantityOrdSub and it is the box that takes quantity, this text box multiplies it with the unit price (DLOOKUP function which works). The output must instantly go into SubTotalValue text box and it this textbox has a control source = Subtotal

```
Private Sub QuantityOrdSub_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
  Me.SubTotalValue.Value = (DLookup("UnitPrice", "Stock", "StockID=" & Int(Me.StockSearchID.Value))) * 
  (Int(Me.QuantityOrdSub.Value))
End Sub
```

To restate, I am trying to update a text box instantly on key stroke.

Comment: @KostasK. I accidently forgot to put it when i was typing the function here. The function does produce correct output but it provides after 1 more extra number. Suppose unit price is $5, when i press "2" nothing happens, but when i press "23", the output comes out to be $10. So its one stroke late

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want instant calculation, I wouldn't monitor the `KeyPress()` event. Instead, I would have the control report when its value changes, therefore I'd monitor the `Change()` event.

```
Private Sub QuantityOrdSub_Change()
    With QuantityOrdSub
        If Len(.Text) > 0 Then
            SubTotalValue.Value = DLookup("UnitPrice", "Stock", "StockID=" & StockSearchID.Value) * Int(.Text)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: so if i have a combo box should i choose on click or on change?

Comment: I'd say `Change()` or `AfterUpdate()`. Keep in mind Andre's second point regarding `.Text` and `.Value`. If you go for Change, you'll check the .Text property and for AfterUpdate the .Value.

Comment: So basically, you are aware that its a continuous form and i am have many items is there way i can restrict if the item is to be chosen again. I.e first part in continous form i choose banana then second line continuous form i choose apple and then after that i choose banana, is there a way i can restrict or alerting the user of repetition in access form.

Comment: Not sure how is this related to the calculation above. Anyway, there are a few ways you can handle this using the `Enter()` and `Exit()` events. If that's the case, please ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1) The correct event to use is `On Change`, i.e. `Private Sub QuantityOrdSub_Change`, not `KeyPress`.

2) `.Value` of the textbox isn't updated until you leave the control. To get the entered text while the user is typing, you must use `.Text`, i.e. `Me.QuantityOrdSub.Text`.